# Method 'Copy' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

For the first time I now faced the error

> Method 'Copy' of object '_Worksheet' failed

I heard that this is a quite common error but I was not able to find a solution. When I searched trough SO, I found many posts about the

> 'Range' of object failed-Error.

Is this error caused by memory limitations of the workstation or is it a software related error?

Anyone got an idea to work around that problem?

In case it is of interest that is my VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "Message"

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
  wb.Sheets(1).Name = "deletethissheet"

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
  Next

  For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    ws.UsedRange.Formula = ws.UsedRange.Value

    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
      sh.Delete
    Next

  Next

  For Each Link In wb.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
  wb.BreakLink Name:=Link, Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
  Next

  wb.Sheets("deletethissheet").Delete
  wb.SaveAs Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", "_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

`ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)`
Is the cause of the error.

Comment: Your code does not arise any error for me. I could create the workbook and copy the worksheets, so there must be something else. Myabe any of the worksheets of worbook itself it's protected? Have you tried debugging with F8 and check if it fails at first loop or a specific worksheet?

Comment: Could you try `After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)`. `Sheet` can also refer to `Charts`, which may cause an error.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns First loop fails at ```ws.copy After:=wb.sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)```
I heared about the fact that it is not reproducable for everyone therefore I am wondering why the error is occuring. Have you got any ideas to go around the ```ws.copy``` function?

Comment: @MG92 Great idea! Unfortunately its not working..

Comment: what about if you try to add a normal workbook not based on any template? with `Set wb = Workbooks.Add` Also, What version of Excel? Windows or Mac?

Comment: The only thing I can think about is that `Worksheets` is a collection, which is `0`-Based. Therefore you could try `After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count-1)`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns not working either, its Excel for Windows

Comment: @MG92 also not working unfortunately
I just tried to copy everthing to a new excel file manually and ran the script without any buttons and now it works. Very interesting. Maybe its because all the cells are formatted?

Comment: the source file, is it XLS? what do you mean with *all the cells are formatted*?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns source file is xlsm but the copy should be saved as xls and all the formulas should be replaced by plain text..
all the cells in the first sheet were formatted with a color. I guess this should not be a problem because there is no data in it but idk. I copied it manually and it ran fine one time. Not it throws out a ```runtime error 13 Types incompatible``` at ```For Each Link In wb.LinkSources(xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
  wb.BreakLink Name:=Link, Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
  ```

Comment: My last shot: You already said the file is XLSM. Where is this code saved? in a form object? in the personal macros workbook?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I tried both in a module as well as directly in the workbook both did not work.

Comment: @MG92 `Sheets` and `Worksheets` are 1-based...

Comment: @Jochen Didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite intensive research, I could not find any details about this error. The solution, which turned out to be very easy for me, was to manually copy everything onto a new sheet and start the macro from there. This error may be caused by limited resources or bad cells.

The VBA itself works. If anyone runs into this kind of problem rebuilding the sheet may work.

Answer (score 2):

Its a year old post, but in-case anyone else finds their way here, I received this error too and solved it. I was trying to use the .copy function on a hidden worksheet. As soon as I unhid the sheet, the macro functioned without error. By adding `Worksheets("Sheet1").visible = True` before .Copy code and `Worksheets("Sheet1").visible = False` at the end of the code it fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old but I also found a possible cause on the official MS documentation:

> Source and Destination must be in the same Excel.Application instance,
> otherwise it will raise a runtime error '1004': No such interface
> supported, if something like Sheet1.Copy objWb.Sheets(1) was used, or
> a runtime error '1004': Copy method of Worksheet class failed, if
> something like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy objWb.Sheets(1)
> was used.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Copy

This is definitely the cause in my case. Hope it helps you too!

EDIT: Instead I just copied the Range.CurrentRegion starting from A1 to the other worksheet and that seemed to be working across multiple application instances. Example mockup:

```
        Dim rg As Range
        Dim xl As Application
        Dim wb As Workbook
        
        Set xl = New Excel.Application
        Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\foo.xlsx")
        Set rg = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        
        rg.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
```