# VBA Excel Autoincrement the string value when looping

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have got a list including the number of flats.

[image]

which I want to have populated in the string here

[image]

now I would like to have it incremented by 1 for every sheet I am going to generate by the loop as below:

```
 Sub otdr()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim xNumber As Long
 Dim otdr As Range
 Dim xName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set ws = Sheets("OTDR TRACE - 1")
 Set otdr = ws.Range("Q46")
 xNumber = Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D32").Value


 For i = 1 To (xNumber - 1)
 otdr = "OT " & (i + 1) & " of " & Number
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "OTDR TRACE - " & (i + 1)
 Next

 ws.Activate
 otdr = "OT 1 of " & Number

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

after implementation of the existing code, it stopped work. I created the 2nd loop, but the string is copied, but without changing the numbers.

```
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim xNumber As Long, yNumber As Long
  Dim otdr As Range, desc As Range
  Dim xName As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wk As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set ws = Sheets("OTDR TRACE - 1")
 Set wk = Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet")
 Set otdr = ws.Range("Q46")
 Set desc = ws.Range("N7")
 xNumber = Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D32").Value
 yNumber = Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet").Range("E3").Value

 For i = 1 To (xNumber - 1)
 otdr = "OT " & (i + 1) & " of " & xNumber
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "OTDR TRACE - " & i + 1
 Next

 For j = 1 To Number
 desc = "FIBRE TRACE @ 1310 & 1550 - F1 - Flat " & j    ' copying only the string without the increment numeration
 ws.Copy After:=ws.Range("N7")(ws.Index + i) ' this line generates an error

 Next


 ws.Activate
 otdr = "OT 1 of " & xNumber
```

Once added

```
    ws.Copy After:=ws.Range("N7")(ws.Index + i)
```

I am getting the following error:

**Method 'Copy of Object' worksheet failed**

The solution below:

[Method 'Copy' of object '_Worksheet' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205862/method-copy-of-object-worksheet-failed)

wasn't helpful for me

Is there a chance to have this number incremented by sheet?

**UPDATE:**

Now my code looks like this:

```
  Sub otdr()

  Dim i As Long, j As Long, Lastrow As Long
  Dim xNumber As Long, yNumber As Long
  Dim otdr As Range, desc As Range
  Dim xName As String
  Dim ws As Worksheet, wk As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set ws = Sheets("OTDR TRACE - 1")
  Set wk = Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet")
  Set otdr = ws.Range("Q46")
  Set desc = ws.Range("N7")
  xNumber = Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D32").Value
 
  Lastrow = wk.Cells(wk.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 1 To (xNumber - 1)
  otdr = "OT " & (i + 1) & " of " & Number
  ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)

  ActiveSheet.Name = "OTDR TRACE - " & i + 1

  Next

  For j = 1 To Lastrow
  desc = "FIBRE TRACE @ 1310 & 1550 - F1 - Flat " & j

  Next


  ws.Activate
  otdr = "OT 1 of " & Number

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True



  End Sub
```

**UPDATE II**

For the following situation:

```
   For i = 1 To (xNumber - 1)
   otdr = "OT " & (i + 1) & " of " & Number
   ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)

   ActiveSheet.Name = "OTDR TRACE - " & i + 1
   For j = 1 To Lastrow
   desc = "FIBRE TRACE @ 1310 & 1550 - F1 - Flat " & j
   Worksheets("OTDR TRACE - 1").Range("N7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("OTDR TRACE - " & j + 1).Range("N7")

   Next

 Next
```

I am getting "We can't do it for a merged cells" for the following line:

```
      Worksheets("OTDR TRACE - 1").Range("N7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("OTDR TRACE - " & j + 1).Range("N7")
```

Comment: If you look at Help you'll see that you copy a worksheet before or after another sheet. You can't copy a sheet after a range, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code. Your second loop is, I think, supposed to say:

```
For j = 1 To yNumber
```

Do you have:

```
Option Explicit
```

at the top of your module? If not, add it (and get in the habit of doing so), then VBA will require you to declare your variables and throw an error for variable typos (where the typo results in a variable that has not been declared).

I'm then unsure of the intention of the line that is failing:

```
ws.Copy After:=ws.Range("N7")(ws.Index + i)
```

But it's certainly not correct.  If you are trying to set the value of Range("N7") in one of the worksheets, then you should do that directly, not using ws.Copy. If that *is* what you're trying to do, then the syntax is like this:

```
Worksheets("<name>").Range("<range>").Value = <value>
```

Edit, 2020/12/08:

Further to your comments and clarification, you're still trying to do the copy and paste in one go, which is why you're having issues debugging it. Split the line that is failing into two using a variable (declare it at the top though):

```
Dim strValue As String ' Or whichever type is appropriate

...

strValue = Worksheets("OTDR TRACE - 1").Range("N7").Value
Sheets("OTDR TRACE - " & j + 1).Range("N7").Value = strValue
```

I suspect that you will still get the merged cells error when trying to set the value, but then you are clear what the issue is and can work out a solution.  I'm not on a machine with Excel at the moment, but you may find that you need to use the other typical way of grabbing the cell value which is:

```
Cells(row, col)
```

so, in your case:

```
Worksheets("OTDR TRACE - 1").Cells(7, 14).Value
```

Comment: Good spot and good advice though not the cause of OP's reported problem. The fact that he didn't report this error means OE definitely not being used.

Comment: I have got all these things. I am really sorry I forgot to add Number.
The error comes despite of it.

Comment: Edited answer to ask the intention of the line that is failing.

Comment: I want to do it directly but by the loop. I tried something like this, but not working:

desc = "FIBRE TRACE @ 1310 & 1550 - F1 - Flat " & Index + j

Comment: @MKR, you still haven't explained what the intention is of the line after that - the one that is failing. If you explain in words what that line is attempting to do, we have a better chance of fixing it for you.

Comment: OK the line after that should increment the value in the string, which you can see in the image. I have got the "Flat 11" there and I need to have this number incremented as the new sheet is added.In the first image you can see, that "flat 11" is in the cell E3. For newly populated sheet (copied by the existing code) I would lille to have the value from E4, E5 and so on. These values come from another sheet.

Comment: @MKR, I'm still not 100% clear, but I think then that you just need to use the code from the last part of my answer to set the cell value in the sheet that you *already copied*. If you are trying to write it to a cell in another new sheet, then you need to create the additional sheet first and then write the value to the cell. There is no way in VBA to create a new sheet and also change one of its cells values in a single line of code.

Comment: I found sth like this: For i = 1 To 5
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i & ":I" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet" & i + 1).Range("D39:K39")
Next

Comment: @RichHarding I have updated the code now. Is it clearer?

Comment: something similar to this:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/auto-increase-a-cell-value-1-when-a-new-sheet-is-created.334786/

Comment: Will append my answer at the bottom.